# ¿Cómo realizar un scatterplot sobre un shapefile en Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

Necesito representar la ubicación de varios puntos de latitud y longitud sobre el mapa de Londres. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
borough = gpd.read_file('London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp')
borough = borough.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8)) 
ax = borough.plot()

x, y = ax(df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values)
ax.scatter(x,y, marker="*", color='r', alpha=0.7, zorder=5, s=9)
plt.show
```

df2 es mi dataframe que contiene las coordenadas de latitud y longitud de ciertos puntos de Londres.

```
$type   additionalProperties    children    childrenUrls    commonName  id  lat lon placeType   url
0   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.P...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addi...   []  []  River Street , Clerkenwell  BikePoints_1    51.529163   -0.109970   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_1
1   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.P...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addi...   []  []  Phillimore Gardens, Kensington  BikePoints_2    51.499606   -0.197574   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_2
2   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.P...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addi...   []  []  Christopher Street, Liverpool Street    BikePoints_3    51.521283   -0.084605   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_
```

Además mi shapefile tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
NAME    GSS_CODE    HECTARES    NONLD_AREA  ONS_INNER   SUB_2009    SUB_2006    geometry
0   Kingston upon Thames    E09000021   3726.117    0.000   F   None    None    POLYGON ((516401.6 160201.8, 516407.3 160210.5...
1   Croydon E09000008   8649.441    0.000   F   None    None    POLYGON ((535009.2 159504.7, 535005.5 159502, ...
2   Bromley E09000006   15013.487   0.000   F   None    None    POLYGON ((540373.6 157530.4, 540361.2 157551.9...
```

Mi problema es que obtengo la siguiente gráfica en donde no aparecen los puntos del df2, ¿como puedo corregir el código para visualizarlos? ¿Cómo hacer la figura más grande?

[image: Imagen incorrecta]

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto problema es porque la ubicición dentro el shapefile no se ha escrito en "geographic coordinates" (lat, lon), asi que usted debe cambiarlo.

Este respuesta (en ingles) en una pregunta similar podria ayudarla:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232508/83426

Comment: Gracias @Heath, ahora el problema que tengo es que los puntos de mi gráfica no están sobre el mapa si no en otra ubicación. Actualizo la pregunta por si puedes ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Creo que tal vez esta usando proyecciones diferentes entre sus puntos de lat/lon y su shapefile. Puede comprobar como asi: `borough.crs`. Este enlace muestra como podria cambiarlo si tiene que hacerlo: http://geopandas.org/projections.html#re-projecting

Comment: he cambiado un poco el código y he transformado borough, pero tampoco puedo representar el scatterplot, podrías echarle un vistazo al código y ayudarme a ver el error? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que no debes usar `ax` por sus puntos de lat/lon. Si cambia como asi: `x, y = df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values`  funciona?

Comment: Funciona! Muchas gracias @Heath. Una pregunta más, ¿sabes cómo podría resaltar en otro color una determinada ciudad del mapa?

Comment: No sé totalmente, pero creo que tal vez podria usar la misma manera como este enlace: http://darribas.org/gds15/content/labs/lab_03.html en linea 26. ¡Espero que ese ayude!

Comment: Y también, si cree que la ayudó y si quiere, por favor marque esta respuesta como "aceptado".